# knockout click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
<div class="icon-upload" data-bind="click: button('upload') "> Upload </div>

ko.bindingHandlers.button = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        //alert('works');
        console.log(element);
    }
};
```

But I keep getting a `button is not defined` error. I'm trying to do an `on('click')` event with a parameter to determine latter what binding to initialize.

For example, when clicking on `button('upload')` I want to initialize the following `binding`

```
ko.bindingHandlers.image = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context)
        {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                $element = $(element);
                console.log($element)

            $element.html(value);

            /*$element.pluploadQueue({
                runtime: 'gears, browserplus, html5, flash, html4',
                max_file_size: '10mb',
                max_file_count: 10,
                chunk_size: '1mb',
                unique_names: true,
                multiple_queues: true,
                drop_element: true,
                dragdrop: true,
                filters : [
                    {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
                ]
            });*/
        }
    };
```

- Do I must wrap the click code in a `ViewModel = function() {` like in

  - http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/xSKyR/
  - http://jsfiddle.net/FpSWb/  ?
- Can't I do it the way I'm trying to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doing it wrong. You should create custom binding `button` which will be triggered on `click` event.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.button = {
   init: function (element) {
      $(element).click(function() {
          // Your logic
      });
   }

   update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      switch(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())) {
          case 'upload': ...
      }
   }
}
```

In view

```
<div class="icon-upload" data-bind="button: 'upload'"> Upload </div>
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try it this way than

Comment: I did it another way after all... but I'll take your answer for accepted